# right padding overwrites the margin

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

looking at this live demo:http://jsfiddle.net/5AUMA/25/

How do I make the left sidebar text be right justified but about 1% away from the right margin.

When I do the `padding-right: 1%;` it starts overwriting the margin

Also how do I make the circle be above the text?

EDIT - just edited the link

Comment: ABOVE the text? it's above already. Do you mean the text inside the circle?

Comment: @Fabio see the link again .. its to the list of the circle .. I need it to be at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

You could use on the `.left` class:

```
direction:rtl;
text-indent: 1%;
```

Another option would be:

Create a `div` inside `.left` and call it `.inner-left`, then add this CSS to your code:

```
// HTML
<div class="left">
    <div class="inner-left">
        LEFT
    </div>
</div>

// CSS
.inner-left {
    text-align: right;
    width: 95%; /* change this value if you need */
}
```

ps: don't forget to run the jsfiddle to test the changes

Hope it helps.

Comment: what does the direction: rtl do? Also how do I make sure my text is displayed below the circle image in the left sidebar

Comment: @sukhvir I can't see the circle image you are talking about, maybe you forgot to update the jsfiddle. I've updated my answer, see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best bet is to use the box model to set margins/paddings and use text-align properties and margin auto along with setting how the object should display( block,inline,etc). I played a little with the fiddle example you gave and used the box model to set the element properly inside the parent. Sorry that I used inline CSS but it is just an example that you can extract and transfer to your main CSS file.

Here is the new fiddle test: **http://jsfiddle.net/5AUMA/26/**

and the box model reference is here: ***http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp***

the code example just in case (but the fiddle has it all complete):

```
<div class="left">
<div style="padding-right:5%; display:block; text-align:right;" >
    <img style="margin:auto; margin-right:0; max-width:50%; max-height:50%; display:block;"  src="http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v436/passion4architecture/LOGO_ROUND%20and%20CIRCLE/Logo_The-Circle-of-Reason_wwwcircleofreasonorg_dian-hasan-branding_US-2_zpsf675b4a5.png" />
    hello
    </div>

LEFT
```

This should help with all your current needs.

Ps: for any element (including images) is better to use css to adjust the widths/heights and alignments.

Cheers :)

Comment: cheers ... how would I put that in css. would it be possible for you to do all the above in css .. including image size?

Comment: easy, just remove the inline CSS and assign classes to the elements. And in your CSS file write those classes with the attributes/rules of the inline CSS, so it will be like this: .left-top-box { rules_here } (assigned to the div holding the image) and .left-top-box-image {rules_here} (assigned the image itself). happy coding ;)